# ST_DWithin of a PolygonZ and point geometry

Tags: postgis

Convex_hull is a column of PolygonZ type (with 0 as the third dimension for all rows). geoJson is a point geometry. Can I use the function as follows correctly? The following code runs without error, but I am uncertain whether the PolygonZ type is causing additional overhead, or giving inaccurate results.

```
ST_DWithin(c.convex_hull::geography, cp.geoJson::geography, 20)
```

Comment: if the Z is 0 for everything just use the st_force2d function to get rid of it

Comment: I think what you're asking is whether the z dimension is being analyzed by st_dwithin and causing extra overhead.  The answer is no.  To answer the question as worded, you're using the function correctly.  It accepts 2d or 3d or 4d geometries.  But it only analyzes the 2d distance.  The z or m or whatever extra dim won't affect the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs don't explicitly state that it's the 2D distance that is being compared. It is the 2D distance that's being compared. This is a standard geometry function and it only considers X and Y. If the documentation does not explicitly state that it is a 3D function, you can assume it's doing all the work in 2D only and ignoring any other dimensions. Drop the z. You don't need it. Why are you keeping it?

And another interesting thing about your data is that it would make no difference whether you used st_3ddwithin or st_dwithin (other than lower performance).  There's no variation in your z dimension, so there is no added length and no difference between the 2D and 3D distance.